# How do i stop update button if my quantity drops to 0?

Tags: php, javascript, sql

In a cart page, user can update the quantity of an item(default when added is 1) so how do i stop the user from updating the quantity OR stop the updating process if the new quantity will drop the current quantity to 0 or below?

This is the code:

```
function showCart() {
global $db;
$cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
if ($cart) {
    $items = explode(',', $cart);
    $contents = array();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $contents[$item] = (isset($contents[$item])) ? $contents[$item] + 1 : 1;
    }
    $output[] = '<form action="cart.php?action=update" method="post" id="cart">';

    $output[] = '<table border = "1" class ="table">';
    $output[] = '<tr height = "40">';
    $output[] = '<td width="168" align="center">&nbsp</td>';
    $output[] = '<td width="168" align="center">Title</td>';
    $output[] = '<td width="168" align="center">Author</td>';
    $output[] = '<td width="168" align="center">Price</td>';
    $output[] = '<td width="168" align="center">Quantity</td>';
    $output[] = '<td width="168" align="center">Total Amount</td>';
    $output[] = '<tr >';
    foreach ($contents as $id => $qty) {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = ' . $id;
        $result = $db->query($sql);
        $row = $result->fetch();
        extract($row);
        $output[] = '<tr height ="40" >';
        $output[] = '<td width ="140" align="center"><a href="cart.php?action=delete&id=' . $id . '" class="r"><img alt=""  src="image/x.png" width = "30px" height="30px"></a></td>';
        $output[] = '<td width ="140" align="center">' . $name . '</td>';
        $output[] = '<td width ="140" align="center">' . $author . '</td>';
        $output[] = '<td width ="140" align="center">SGD' . $price . '</td>';
        $output[] = '<td width ="140" align="center"><input type="text" name="qty' . $id . '" value="' . $qty . '" size="3" maxlength="3" /></td>';
        $output[] = '<td width ="140" align="center" >SGD' . ($price * $qty) . '</td>';
        $total += $price * $qty;
        $output[] = '</tr>';
    }
    $output[] = '<tr>';
    $output[] = '<td>';
    $output[] = '<center>';
    $output[] = '<div class = "update_button"><button type="submit" >Update cart</button></div>';
    $output[] = '</center>';
    $output[] = '</td>';        
    $output[] = '<td colspan ="5" align="right">';
    $output[] = '<p>Grand total: <strong>SGD:' . $total . '</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>';
    $output[] = '</td>';
    $output[] = '</tr>';
    $output[] = '</table>';


    $output[] = '</form>';
    $output[] = '<br>';
} else {
    $output[] = '<center>';
    $output[] = '<br><h3>You shopping cart is empty.</h3><br>';
    $output[] = '</center>';
}
return join('', $output);
```

}

Comment: What is the value of putting each line of HTML into an array and then imploding them? Inline string concatenation is better for this use. Also why not use a multidimensional array for your cart in the session instead of a CSV list that you have to explode on read.

Answer (score 2):

Are You the author of shown code? I assume that You are trying to modify someone else's code and thus I explain bit more throughly:

The code that You have shown does not update anything. The PHP code You have shown takes the shopping cart content from $_SESSION parameter and inserts it into $contents array.

```
$cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
$items = explode(',', $cart);
$contents = array();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $contents[$item] = (isset($contents[$item])) ? $contents[$item] + 1 : 1;
}
```

$contents is now an array.

After that SQL query is made for each product in $contents, to find out product details, such as name, author, etc.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = ' . $id;
$result = $db->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch();
extract($row);
```

Then a HTML table is produced that contains each of the products and a field to change the quantity of product.

The $output variable contains the HTML table, but the HTML table is never outputted.

I assume that You have only shown us part of the code from a bigger system. To answer Your question, You should show us the PHP code that has to do with processing the POST request and updating the data.

EDIT: As seen from code

```
'<form action="cart.php?action=update" method="post" id="cart">';
```

the POST data is sent to file cart.php?action=update when You click "update" button. So You should show us some more code from cart.php.

Comment: Nope, im not the author of the shown code. This code is edited once by me. However i was thinking if i can get $quantity from my db and insert a if statement to show an alert?

Comment: The problem is that this code only defines the <form>. When You click "update", data is sent to page "cart.php?action=update". You should paste some code from cart.php (edit Your own post, don't create an answer)

Comment: i have added the processing part. i believe

Comment: I don't see it. In Your post I only see the function showCart(). But when user clicks on "Update Cart", the POST data is sent to page cart.php . You should show more code from cart.php. Are You familiar with GET and POST request and how they work? If no, here is good place to start: [www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are updating table and decrease qty by 1 when someone purchase it..

when your qty hits to 0 in db table then dont put purchase button..

or dont fetch from table when qty is 0 or <0

Answer (score 0):

Maintain the total number of Items available at any time in the Model (Model should have the current state of any item). 
Whenever user tries to add items to cart, check if the number of items user is trying to add is more than the number of items available, then give user an alert that these many items are not available.